# How to cancel updates in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

So windows 10 has this annoying habit of downloading updates over WiFi connections not marked as metered connections.

I have to connect to a limited WiFi hotspot, and by the time I set the connection to metered, some updates had already started downloading. So I went to services.msc and stopped windows updater.

Now when I go to Settings->Update and Security->Windows Update, It says "Updates are ready to download". That is just fine, but when I click on "Details" of the updates, some updates still shows 'Downloading'. My bandwidth is not getting used up by this, but a process called "From Microsoft Download/Upload host" is constantly using high amounts of my CPU power, causing heating and battery drain.

How can I solve this problem?
I believe totally cancelling all ongoing updates will solve this, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: What happens when you close or pause this other process, "from Microsoft Download/Upload host".  (What's the real name of this process?).  If you use "Process Explorer" from Microsoft to pause, you'll have the ability to pause, kill, or get more details than you can imagine, including who started it.  Once the download is started, BITS is the process that is actually performing the download, so you may have to pause or stop BITS.

Comment: If you do not want to use the tool suggested by Magicandre1981, here is how to just disable windows update using a reg file, it can re-enabled using another reg file.   http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/8013-windows-update-automatic-updates-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the 3rd party tool called [Windows Update MiniTool](https://wumt.blogspot.com/) which allows to select which updates can be installed and allows to block updates like you could in former Windows versions.

[image]

> An alternative to the standard Windows Update What you can do:
>  • Check
>   for updates 
>  • Download updates
>  • Installing Updates
>  •
>   Deleting installed updates
>  • Hiding unwanted updates
>  • Get
>   direct links to the *.cab / *.Exe / *.Psf update files • View update
>   history
>  • **Configure Automatic Updates**
>  • This tool is like the
>   external powershell module PSWindowsUpdate, but much more advanced and
>   user-friendly features
>  • The tool relies and use same WU
>   infrastructure, all downloading are through WU it's not a
>   downloader

Here you can change the checking mode to only notify about updates and download the updates manually when you are at a unlimited internet connection.

Comment: Download Link for latest versions.  https://cloud.mail.ru/public/3E95/kvd9WCbUq

Comment: For some reason, magicandre1981 likes to link to an outdated versions. I noticed this in another of his answers to another question. I use Softpedia to download the latest version.