# How to completely destroy Windows 10 Updater?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, sleep, wake-on-lan

So I've tried the following:

- Disabled the Windows Update Service
- Enabled `No auto-restart with logged o users for scheduled automatic update`
- Set Windows Update to `Notify to Schedule Restart` and `Defer Upgrade`
- In Power Options, disabled Wake Timers under Sleep
- In Task Scheduler > Microsoft > Windows > UpdateOrchestrator disabled Reboot task

Yet it never fails to wake up at 6 AM sharp, starting up the computer and running all the fans at full power... waking ME up because it's in the same room.

Is there a way to completely remove this stupid automatic update? I don't know why something so simple requires so much effort to do.

Comment: You can't disable Windows Update on Windows 10 Hime or Windows 10 Professional ( only defer updates on Professional )

Comment: use this 3rd party tool: http://superuser.com/a/1024799/174557 and here you can disable automatic update.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Microsoft's Windows 10......

Comment: @Ramhound - Isn't that a bit misleading? There are ways to do so. One that comes to mind is setting your WIFI connections to "metered". Correct me if I misunderstand your message.

Comment: Is it really about Windows Update at all? `It never fails to wake up at 6AM sharp`? Sounds like you're getting updates every day but that can't be true? What if you disable the network adapters before going to sleep?

Comment: @Bort - How is it misleading.  So you set the connection to metered, Windows will not update, until your not on a metered connection.  End Result: Windows Update is enabled.  You you can defer updates in Windows 10 Professional for a period of time, eventually, you are forced to install them.  End Result: Windows Update is enabled.  The best option would be to use WSUS (or MiniTool) which lets you push the updates you want to your system., when you want them, but you can do that with Windows Update also.

Comment: I suspect the underline problem. of the machine attempting to update at 6AM, could be fixed by manually modifying the task itself or setting it to update a different time.

Comment: Any other tasks in Task Scheduler > Microsoft/Windows/WindowsUpdate?

Answer (score -1):

***Group Policy***
If your version of Windows 10 has Group Policy, you can also change some settings using the Group Policy Editor. Run gpedit and navigate to the following policy setting:

Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update.

Select ***Enabling Windows Power management to Automatically Wake up the system to Install Scheduled updates  ***

[image]

***To disable the scheduled task***

Step 1: 
Open Windows search with the ***Windows Key + S***

Step 2: 
Type or paste ***Task Scheduler*** into the search field

[image: Task Scheduler]

Step 3: 
Delete or disable all instances of Windows update

***Disable the update service in Windows 10 Pro***
You can disable the update service in Windows 10 Pro I'm not sure about Home version

Step 1: 
Press the ***Windows Key + R***

Step 2: 
Type or copy paste ***services.msc*** into run command 
[image: Run Command Box]

Step 3: 
Select ***OK*** at the UAC prompt and scroll down to Windows update

[image: Services.msc scroll box]

Step 4: 
Double click on Windows update and in Windows Update properties set the ***Start-up Type*** to ***Disable*** then press ***OK***

[image: Windows Update properties]

Step 5: 
Restart your computer to apply the settings

Comment: This would stop the Windows Update service, it does not remove the requirement, of staying update.  Of course on the other hand the author clearly indicate that they already disabled the service you indicate they should disable.

Comment: That services screenshot is comedy. On a serious note tho this would completely disable the Windows updater service which I wouldn't recommend.

Comment: @Geditdk He didn't ask for what's recommended

Comment: @Ramhound I edited my answer

Comment: @user221429 - He also already tried what you originally described.

Comment: @Ramhound Added another edit for Gpedit

Comment: Performed all steps above a while ago, today Windows Update *disabled* service started on it's own and started installing updates....

Comment: As of this writing other Windows services re-enable Windows update if you disable it, and you cannot disable those services. This answer was correct, but has been overruled by the -- I am going to say it -- excess arrogance of the chief engineers of Windows. It is patently anti-user to force a disabled service back on _via other services which cannot be disabled_. A possible workaround is setting the update service to run as user "guest."