# Page faults not available in process explorer

Tags: windows, memory

In this answer (sencond part/process explorer):

https://superuser.com/a/1270689/1160187

it's suggested that page faults can be viewed per process in process explorer. But in my case, I don't have the options described in the answer:

[process explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r64EL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to View > Select Columns > Process Memory

[image: Check it]

Comment: Thanks! Can you upvote the question so that I can use the site XD