# Missing confirmation of changes to "group policy"/"configure automatic updates"

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

**For the record, I dispute that this question is already answered elsewhere on SO.**

I just upgraded from Windows 10 home to Windows 10 Pro purely because I have heard that it is only possible to prevent the dreaded forced reboot issue with home. I followed the first few steps in the solution given => [here](https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10) and got to the following screen:

[image]

The instructions state "configure it as needed"... but it appears that the default *is already* what I need, i.e. download automatically but then wait for me to manually give permission to install (& reboot). So I just clicked "OK". The instructions go on to say that I should go to the advanced options part of windows update and I should see the words "Some settings are managed by your organisation" in red writing in the window. But I see no such thing. All I see is the following:

[image]

Did I do something wrong? Maybe in the most recent versions of pro my desired behaviour is the default? Maybe in the most recent versions Microsoft chose not to show the red writing any more?

Comment: You do understand that Windows 10 Professional will still required you to install security updates, you can only defer updates for a period of time, eventually those updates will be installed and a reboot will be required.  As for the group policy your attempt to use, it doesn't apply to Windows 10 Professional 1607+, starting with 1607 that particular group policy is ignored on every version of Windows except Education and Enterprise.

Comment: The solution to your problem, is the same as it was on Windows 10 Home, mark your ethernet as metered.

Comment: Use the [Windows Update MiniTool](https://superuser.com/a/1024799/174557) to configure the WU settings and set to just notify

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed new answer... and I may well award it the bounty. The only thing stopping me implementing it immediately is that it feels rather, ermm, drastic. Forcefully shutting down something just make me feel uncomfortable - will the task being shut down correctly tidy up everything that it started. I'll be happier when it's had more upvotes  (I see it has a couple already).

Comment: Another thing is that Erwin's reboot blocker answer seems super simple. If that works then perhaps that should get my vote , especially now that Erwin answered my question I put in a comment.- my only issue is that it only has three upvotes, which seems strange given the immense popularity of the question and the length of time it's been up.

Comment: You certainly have gone above and beyond, maybe I'll award you the bounty  just for effort... but unless I'm informed that Erwin's answer is flawed, I can't help but prefer its simplicity. Currently I'm just disturbed that many much more complicated answers have so many more upvotes.

Comment: Hey Mick, thanks for the follow up. The only thing I can say that could be negative about the reboot-blocker tool is that it's third party, it's freeware and not open source so you do not know what the logic of the EXE is doing even though it's been confirmed not malicious so the potential to wonder perhaps is there whereas my answer is native and not third party, and you see and control and can change exactly what it does.

Comment: If you do decide to give me the bounty, I would be forever grateful indeed and I'd be extremely thrilled. However, it is not a problem problem for me regardless, you choose what you like best and perhaps others can utilize my answer in the future. My answer is a bit more complex to get setup but once setup it's simple to maintain. I appreciate your comments back, etc. regardless and good luck with everything.

Comment: If you want this policy to work like it did in previous versions of Windows (i.e. Install updates daily at 3 AM and reboot at that time) you must enable the policy `Always automatically restart at the scheduled time` found in the same Windows Update node of Group Policy. [Full details here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wsus/2013/10/08/enabling-a-more-predictable-windows-update-experience-for-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012-kb-2885694/).

Comment: @magicandre1981 - why don't you post your minitool solution as an answer to https://superuser.com/questions/957267/how-to-disable-automatic-reboots-in-windows-10/1208866#1208866 - if it works you will be helping many thousands of people.

Comment: @Mick I don't think it should be posted there. The user won't search there for the tool